# Search in laravel for booking by User id

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make search for booking by user id but it's give me all booking for all users
I want to know how to retrive all booking by user_id from table booking,
Thanks in advance, Please Note that in offline working very well, but online give me all booking for all users.

```
  <form action="{{url('search',Auth::user()->id)}}" method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Search">Search :</label>
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search Here" type="text" name="search">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-mini deleteRecord">Search</button>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('search/{id}','BookAppointController@search');
```

Controller:

```
public function search(Request $request, $id)
{
    $search=$request->get('search');
    $Allappoints=DB::table('bookappoitments')->where('users_id',$id)
    ->where('gustname','like', '%' .$search. '%')
    ->orwhere('gustcompany','like', '%' .$search. '%')
    ->orwhere('gustemail','like', '%' .$search. '%')

    ->join('times','bookappoitments.times_id','times.id')
    ->join('dates','bookappoitments.Dates_id','dates.id')
    ->select('bookappoitments.*','times.from_to','dates.Dates')->orderBy('times.id')
    ->paginate(10);

   return view('admin.ManageTime.All',compact('Allappoints'));


}
```

Comment: As I am able to see you have used user_id for searching but along with that you have used 'orwhere' which simply a OR condition and returning true.

Comment: also when you searched by userid then what's the need of orwhere

Comment: I must delete Orwhere right

Comment: yes, there is no need. this makes a query like finding by user id or other orwhere conditions

Comment: Ok, Who can I use multiple where in this condetion?

Comment: not getting you

Comment: Thanks alot , I delete Orwhere and working fine but on one column, how can get another columns

Comment: I am really not getting you please be clear

Comment: I want to search in 3 column in one row (gustname,gustcompany and gustemail)

Comment: Explain step by step in a clear way

Comment: ->where('gustname','like', '%' .$search. '%')
    ->orwhere('gustcompany','like', '%' .$search. '%')
    ->orwhere('gustemail','like', '%' .$search. '%')

Comment: searching by gustname OR gustcompany OR gustemail

Comment: you want to apply this in same query. but why?

Comment: To give the user more options

Comment: when you search by userid aren't you getting all details.

Comment: What table structure you are following

Comment: Oh yes, Thanks alot about your helping and your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this format, please

```
public function search(Request $request, $id)
{
    $search=$request->get('search');
    $Allappoints=DB::table('bookappoitments')->where('users_id',$id)- 
    >paginate(10);

   return view('admin.ManageTime.All',compact('Allappoints'));


}
```

Tell me  if any other issue.

Comment: How can I search like : where('name', 'like', '%.$search.%')